# map values to a specific range

Tags: python, mapping

Let say we have some angular values from `-inf` to `+inf` as input.

I'd like to map them between only `-180` and `+180`.

How could I properly achieve that?

Here's what I've found so far:

```
(i-180)%360-180
```

It works fine, but it maps `+180` to `-180` which I would like to be `+180`->`+180`.

Technically it's the same for my purpose so it's not a big deal, but it would be aesthetically better.

I'm working with Python but it doesn't really matter here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't value mathematical aestheticism as much, I think this could work

```
def f(i):
    x = i % 360
    if x > 180:
        x -= 360
    elif x == 180 and i < 0:
        x = -x
    return x
```

Comment: It's working but it sends +180->+180 and -180->+180.     I really want: -180->180 and +180->+180.

Comment: Isn't that a feature? If your scale runs from -180 up to and including +180, you have 361 degrees. Or is my math off?

Comment: I think that's a feature. Well, I've edited my answer for that. 180 -> 180, -180 -> -180.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have values in the range `-inf` to `inf` in a list `sampleList[]`.
You need to map the values in sampleList[] in range `-180` to `180`. Lets name the new list of mapped elements as `mappedList[]`

Consider `x` as element in `sampleList[]`

Consider `y` as element in `mappedList[]`

Consider `maxSL` as maximum of `sampleList[]` and

`minSL` as minimum of `sampleList[]`

Therefore,

```
        y = ((x - minSL)(((180-(-180))/(maxSL - minSL))) + (-180)
```